# Substituir palava no txt usando php

Tags: php, txt

Tenho a seguinte linha no arquivo txt

`#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Globorj.br" tvg-name="GLOBO RJ HD" tvg-logo="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-`

essa linha se repete várias vezes.

eu preciso abrir o txt e trocar a palavra `tvg-name`por `NOME`

eu tentei isso:

`$handler = fopen ( 'uploads/' . $new_name , 'r' ) ;
$nova_palavra = str_replace("tvg-name", "NOME", $handler);`

mas não funcionou...

Comment: Para utilizar com a `str_replace`, utilize `file_get_contents` ao invés de `fopen`.

Comment: o retorno da $handler está vindo de que forma?

Comment: @DiegoBraga Quando utiliza a função `fopen`, a variável retorna um  `resource`. Nesse caso não pode utilizar com a `str_replace` (que espera uma string). No caso dele, apenas com o `file_get_contents`; `file` e `implode`; ou `fopen` + `fread`.

Comment: meu código completo
` $handler = file_get_contents ( 'uploads/' . $new_name , 'r' ) ;
   $nova_palavra = str_replace("tvg-name", "NOME", $handler);
 if ( $handler !== false ) {
     $i = 0 ; 
             $dados = array ( ) ;
  while ( ! feof ( $handler ) ) {
 $linha = fgets ( $handler ) ;
 $info = explode ( ';', $linha ) ;
 $dados [ $i ] [ 'Excluir' ] = $info [ 0 ] ;
                    $dados [ $i ] [ 'Nome' ] = trim ( $info [ 1 ] ) ;
     $dados [ $i ] [ 'Link' ] = trim ( $info [ 2 ] ) ;
                ++ $i ;
             }fclose ( $handler ) ;print_r ( $dados ) ;
      } `